# Unable to import Repo from git in google colab even when git is installed

Tags: git, github, repository, google-colaboratory, git-clone

I want to download lightgbm package and clone https://github.com/google-research/google-research.git to the current directory in google colaboratory (colab).

The code that I have used for installing the lightbgm package is as follows

```
# Uses pip3 to install necessary package (lightgbm)
!pip3 install lightgbm

# Resets the IPython kernel to import the installed package.
import IPython
app = IPython.Application.instance()
app.kernel.do_shutdown(True)
```

Upon execution there are pop ups like "your session crashed for an unknown reason", "runtime restarted after crash", etc.
The message on the notebook after execution is

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: lightgbm in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from lightgbm) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from lightgbm) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from lightgbm) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scikit-learn->lightgbm) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scikit-learn->lightgbm) (3.1.0)
{'status': 'ok', 'restart': True}
```

The second part of the code which is mainly for git cloning is as follows

```
import os
from git import Repo

# Current working directory
repo_dir = os.getcwd() + '/repo'

if not os.path.exists(repo_dir):
    os.makedirs(repo_dir)

# Clones github repository
if not os.listdir(repo_dir):
    git_url = "https://github.com/google-research/google-research.git"
    Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir)
```

The error is no module named 'git'. Whereas when I type `!git version` it shows `git version 2.17.1`.

Any ideas where I am going wrong and why the code is not working are highly appreciated. Also is there an alternative code for cloning this repository (in google colab)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-git), while Git is installed, you might also need GitPython.

See this [Google colab example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wT6ZpKLNr24R5qEfH-0jotifhBVrfA9S)

```py
# install gitPython
!pip install gitPython
# clone my repository that contains the selenium chrome profiles
import os
import git


%cd /content
repository_path = "{リポジトリ名}"
if not os.path.isdir(repository_path):
    git.Git().clone("https://{アクセストークン}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/{ユーザー名}/" + repository_path + ".git")
```